# Sharing data within a Python module

Tags: python, module

I have written some Python libraries and structured them as a module. All files within the module require some data from a text file to work. The easiest solution would be to let each library read the file whenever they need it. However, reading the same file several times seems inefficient.
I would prefer to read the file just once and share these data among the different libraries. I could write an additional library to read the data upon initialization and store it in a global variable, so it can be imported by other libraries afterwards.
Although that may work, I still think that this solution is not the most elegant. Is there any best practice for this kind of problem?

Comment: What kind of data is it?

Comment: Let's say it is a configuration file written in YAML containing some user preferences. These parameters won't take much memory, so I would keep them loaded for as long as the module runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is supposed to be used commonly among modules, use should create a file called constants inside your package and initialize the variable with file contents in it. As an afterthought, init file of package is also good candidate for such kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a configuration you could also rewrite it in python and do like some softwares (for instance : django).
Django's configuration is in a file named settings.py.
You can import it with something like :

```
from django.conf import settings
```

And you can use what's within by using `settings.some_variable`.

I hope it will help.